# how is the output of the statement is 'E'

Tags: c, arrays, implicit-conversion, string-literals, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    printf("ABCDE" + sizeof("ABC");/*please explain the output*/
}
```

Output of the program is `E` compiled with `gcc`, please explain

Comment: before that, please explain what you did not understand?

Comment: We're not a tutorial service....

Comment: Did you read about string? Did you read about `sizeof` operator? did you read about indexing?

Comment: Removed C++ tag as there is no implicit `int` in C++.

Comment: Whenever something happens that you don't expect, please **always** include that you expected to happen and why.

Comment: And please use a valid signature for `main`!

Comment: printf("ABCDE"+sizeof("ABC")); prints the value from 4th character, why 4th, this is because of sizeof("ABC"), so it prints E, if you would instead have printf("ABCDE"+ 2); then it would print CDE

Comment: I am new to stack oveflow. Sourav ghosh, if dont want to answer the u can overlook it, no need of giving gyan on it and better learn how to talk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two quotes from the C Standard will make the result clear.

The first one is about string literals (6.4.5 String literals)

> 6 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
>   each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
>   or literals.78) The multibyte character sequence is then used to
>   initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the
>   array elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual
>   bytes of the multibyte character sequence....

And the second one is about implicit conversions (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 **Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator** or the
>   unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array,
>   **an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’** that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So according to the first quote the string literal `"ABC"` is stored as a character array of the type `char[4]` (due to the appended zero) with the static storage duration.

According to the second quote in the expression

```
sizeof("ABC")
```

the array is not converted to a pointer. So in fact this expression is equivalent to the expression

```
sizeof( char[4] )
```

and yields the result equal to `4`.

So the expression

```
"ABCDE" + sizeof("ABC")
```

can be rewritten like

```
"ABCDE" + 4
```

In this expression according to the second quote the string literal `"ABCDE"` that represents itself a character array is converted to the pointer to its first element. Thus there is used the so-called pointer arithmetic.

You can imagine the result of the evaluation of the expression in the function call with the following code snippet

```
char string_literal[6] = "ABCDE";
char *p = &string_literal[0];
printf( p + 4 );
```

the expression `p + 4` points to the character `'E'` and equivalent to `&p[4]` or `&string_literal[4]`

Pay attention to that according to the same C standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

even though a return statement is absent in the function body.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to stack overflow and have created an account just a day back. I have got this question in HCL interview, so I thought of asking this question. Many thank to you.

Comment: HCL is the company working in the INDIA, here is the link of the company https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCL_Technologies

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the terminating `'\0'` byte, 3 + 1 bytes so `"ABCDE"[4]` which is `'E'`.

Also, the correct signature for `main()` is either

1. `int main(void)` or,
2. `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Answer (score 0):

The output of your program is not `E`, it does not compile as posted because there is a missing `)` in `printf("ABCDE" + sizeof("ABC");`

The size of a string constant is the number of bytes inluding the null terminator, hence `sizeof("ABC")` evaluates to `4`.

`"ABCDE" + 4` is the address if the `E` in the string and since the string dos not have any other character after this `E`, the output is the sane as that of `printf("E");`.

Note that the prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)` and for good style, you should return `0` and output a newline.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("ABCDE\n" + sizeof("ABC"));
    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
E
```